# How to trim a video using FFmpeg in Objective-C for iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am trying to implement a sample iOS application that can trim a bundled video (.mp4) using FFmpeg library in Objective-C environment.

I used [this script](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script) to compile and build the FFmpeg for iOS. Those libraries was added to the project but now I'm not sure how to continue it. How can I find which function do the trim behaviour and what are the supportive codecs and etc.

I am interesting do achieve this with out any wrapper but directly accessing the library functions. How can I do this?

***Update : 1***

I believe following code snippet will contain the input video file details in a stream

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"KeseMase" ofType:@".mp4"];

AVInputFormat *inputFormat = av_find_input_format([@"mp4" UTF8String]);

const char *utf8FilePath = [filePath UTF8String];

avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, utf8FilePath, inputFormat, nil);
```

Or does it contain only the header information of the video file?

***Update : 2***

With following code, I was able to convert input video to a stream of AVPacket and store them in a NSMutableArray

```
- (BOOL)readFrameIntoPacket:(AVPacket *)packet error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    BOOL continueReading = YES;

    int frameReadValue = av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, packet);

    if (frameReadValue == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s - %d # Read next frame", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        continueReading = YES;

        NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&packet objCType:@encode(AVPacket)];
        [srcPktArr addObject:value];
    }
    else
    {
        continueReading = NO;
        av_free_packet(packet);
    }
    return continueReading;
}
```

Tasks remain to solve the question are:

1.) How to use those AVPackets to and write a Video file

2.) How to give a start time and end time and write only that part to a video file

***Update : 3***

Okay... then I try to write those packets to an out put file like below

```
- (BOOL)writePacket:(AVPacket *)packet error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    int writeValue = av_write_frame(outputContext, packet);

    if (writeValue == 0)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if (writeValue == 1)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

and ended up with following error

> [mp4 @ 0x1c04a200] Invalid packet stream index: 17467852

***Update : 4***

Okay guys, I get [this far](https://bitbucket.org/AnujAroshA/privaterepo/src/a8f7dc54a80ecea04b61149f0891ace1107e28e2/ViewController.m?at=master).

Comment: Check http://www.codza.com/extracting-frames-from-movies-on-iphone